# webMathematica Settings in Wolfram Workbench

Tags: workbench, webmathematica, eclipse

I have Wolfram Workbench installed in the Eclipse IDE.  Now I am trying to setup the connection in the webMathematica plugin for Workbench to connect to a remote server installed with webMathematica.

In Workbench, Preferences > webMathematica, the input field 'Server Root' is not accepting an IP address (see image below).  It seems to only want a local directory.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I have `C:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0` and I think it used to work (but haven't used it in months).

Comment: Thanks, but this is a remote webMathematica server I need to connect to, hence the IP address.